# Why does not work CSS(margin-bottom) using jQuery in iOS UIWebview?

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, uiwebview

I make the menu view, and when I press a specific button, I want to give margin-bottom to the last menu div.(I use query-2.2.4.min.js)

```
$('.menu_pr').last().css('margin-bottom', height);
```

It works on Android web view in app or general web browser(desktop) but does not work properly in iOS In-App UIWebView. Precisely, the value is applied to the margin-bottom, but it does not move on the screen.(to up) Is there a place I can check?

```
<style>
.menu_pr { cursor: pointer; width: 100%; outline: none; border: none; transition: 0.4s; background-color: #fff; padding: 0 !important; float: left; margin-bottom: 0px;}
</style>


<div class="menu_pr">
    <button class="accordion">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="menu_content">
                <div class="menu_img">
                    <div class="menu_img_pic" style="background: url('hot0001.jpg') no-repeat center center;background-size:contain;">
                        <span class="menu_img_detail" style="display: none;">
                            <img src="menu_detail.png" alt="">
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu_ex"> 
                        <h5>Americano Double</h5>
                    <h5 class="text-grey"><span id="menu_price">₩4,100</span></h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </button>
    <div class="panel" style="max-height: 0px;">
        <section class="menu_option_base margin-bot-10">
            <div class="list">
                <div class="list_title text-grey">CUPS</div>
                <div class="list_content float-right">
                    <div class="choice">
                        <div class="choice_quantity btn_radius_sel">1CUP</div>
                        <div class="choice_quantity btn_radius_desel">2CUP</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="btn_order">
            <button class="btn btn_add">ADD</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```